# Can't sign out of website, can't change credentials in Edge Chromium

Tags: browser, login, microsoft-edge

We have an application that requires authentication.

When I browsed to it for the first time, it asks for a username and password ("This site requires authentication" popup). I type in `SomeDomain\SomeUser`, `SomePassword` and it lets me in, but the code verifies this user against a list and says sorry you don't have access. Fair enough.

I want to switch to another account, `AnotherDomain\AnotherUser`.

However I cannot 'log out'. I have tried deleting cookies, wiping cache, restarting, closing the browser, every time I go back to that website it says within the website's template `SomeDomain\SomeUser is not authorised`.

If I visit the website in incognito mode I get an IIS Error: `401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.` without actually being prompted for any.

If I visit in Firefox, the same behaviour occurs, but deleting firefox browsing history etc. and going back to the site, I am prompted again to enter credentials.

How can I force Edge Chromium to sign out and prompt me again? This behaviour occurs only in Edge (chromium) and I can't get into the website at all. Any ideas?

My locally logged in user is `AnotherDomain\AnotherUser` which is what I want to switch to.

Comment: It sounds like the server records your address as access token. If you can, try with a new IP address.

Comment: Trying with a different browser works but everything is configured in my main browser

Comment: Seems this is a problem within Edge Chromium as in Firefox clearing my browser and going back prompts me again.

Comment: @NibblyPig - What about Edge (EdgeHTML) and/or Chrome (Chromium)?  If you delete the Edge (Chromium) user profile are you able to resolve this issue.  I understand that isn't the perfect solution but the entire point is to isolate the reason the behavior exists.